# Unable to cast error using Box-created RSA key with Box C# SDK project

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, box

Our organization recently adopted Box to replace Windows shared folders.  The small development group I'm a part of will need to upload and download files from at least one Box share and so we are just getting started with the API.

Our group currently uses Visual Studio 2013 to develop in C# with a preferred target of .NET 4.0. The current version of the SDK (2.15.6) isn't compatible with our platform but looking at prior versions it appears we should be able to leverage version 2.12.1 with our existing platform.  The SDK includes a solution with C# methods to access the API calls and a solution with sample code.

Presently I'm trying to get the sample code to consume my credentials and authenticate to the server.

Within the Box developer tools I have created an application and used the built-in Box configuration option to generate a Public/Private keypair which is presented as a JSON file.

Where I'm getting hung up is when I try to use the keypair with the `Box.V2.Samples.JWTAuth` project.  I copied the private key out of the JSON file, replaced the \n's with actual carriage returns, and pasted it into the `private_key.pem` file:

[Private Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYk7c.png)

I placed the other values in app.config and started the console app, which produces an `Unable to cast` error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQcCB.png)

How can I get from a BouncyCastle RsaPrivateCrtKeyParamaters object to a BouncyCastle AsymmetricCipherKeyPair object?

**Edit**

I was able to track down the problematic code block.  From `SDK\Box.V2.JWTAuth\BoxJWTAuth.cs`:

```
        var pwf = new PEMPasswordFinder(this.boxConfig.JWTPrivateKeyPassword);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair key;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(this.boxConfig.JWTPrivateKey))
        {
            key = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader, pwf).ReadObject();
        }
        var rsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)key.Private);
        this.credentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
```

From my reading it seems like the code is anticipating having to extract the Private key from a Public/Private pair which isn't what Box is supplying (at least, not currently) and what I'm supplying appears to already be of the `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters` type so this cast may (no longer be) necessary.

Comment: Sounds like you're boxed in. Perhaps you can post your code.

Comment: I see what you did there.  Code located and added.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you are trying to write code to do this, or trying to configure a tool, but programmatically, it would be:

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters priv = ...;
RSAKeyParameters pub = new RSAKeyParameters(false, priv.getModulus(), priv.getPublicExponent());
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pub, priv);
```

Comment: I tried to clarify; right now I'm trying to use sample code provided within the SDK.

Comment: It seems then that ReadObject is already returning an RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters, in which case, just cast to that and pass to ToRSA, no need for the AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.